# Check xml elements business rules directly with xpath or convert them to java object

Tags: java, xml, validation, xpath

In a java project, consider a file with about `1,000-100,000` xml elements in it. Each xml element needs to be validated with some business rules.

Some of the element nodes are as below:

```
<transfer>
  <bank-id>BIESXXTH</bank-id>
  <from-account>016534412</from-account>
  <to-account>016534412</to-account>
  <amount>765000</amount>
  <transaction-time>2015-08-08T13:34:00</transaction-time>
</transfer>
```

The rules are some thing like:

- `amounts` should be less than `500000000`
- The `from-accounts` should not start with `03`

The size of xml file with `1,000` elements is about `400KB` and the size of file with `100,000` elements the file size will be about `40MB`

To validate the business rules we can:

- Marshal all XML to a **List** object first and then loop through created list, one-by-one and check rules.
- Use xpath to check the rules.

I want to know, which one is better (considering performance and memory usage)?!

Also if any one has same experience, may it come the situation that I could not do what I want with xpath !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File xmlFile = new File(path);

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature(
    "http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd",
    false);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

document = builder.parse(xmlFile); //or parse the String
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

So now you have the xml file as a Document object.

I'd suggest checking each node as it comes up so you don't have to create objects that potentially won't be added to the list.

```
List<Transfer> list = new ArrayList<Transfer>();
NodeList nodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("transfer");

for (int i=0; i<nodelist.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element) nodelist.item(i);

    if (isValidTransfer(element) {
        Transfer t = buildTransferFromElement(element);
        list.add(t);
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can work out how to create the `isValidTransfer` and `buildTransferFromElement` methods.

Give the [W3C Javadoc](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) a read as well, it's pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic xpath to object implementation you can have a look into this.

**Example 1: JavaBean Property Access**

JXPath can be used to access properties of a JavaBean.

```
 public class Employee {
    public String getFirstName(){
       ...
    }
 }

 Employee emp = new Employee();
 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 String fName = (String)context.getValue("firstName");
```

In this example, we are using JXPath to access a property of the emp bean. In this simple case the invocation of JXPath is equivalent to invocation of getFirstName() on the bean.

**Example 2: Nested Bean Property Access**

JXPath can traverse object graphs:

```
 public class Employee {
    public Address getHomeAddress(){
       ...
    }
 }
 public class Address {
    public String getStreetNumber(){
       ...
    }
 }

 Employee emp = new Employee();
 ...

 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 String sNumber = (String)context.getValue("homeAddress/streetNumber");
```

In this case XPath is used to access a property of a nested bean.
A property identified by the xpath does not have to be a "leaf" property. For instance, we can extract the whole Address object in above example:

```
Address addr = (Address)context.getValue("homeAddress");
```

**Example 3: Setting Properties**

JXPath can be used to modify property values.

```
 public class Employee {
    public Address getAddress() {
       ...
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
       ...
    }
 }

 Employee emp = new Employee();
 Address addr = new Address();
 ...

 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 context.setValue("address", addr);
 context.setValue("address/zipCode", "90190");
```

**Example 4: Creating objects**
*JXPath can be used to create new objects. First, create a subclass of AbstractFactory and install it on the JXPathContext. Then call createPathAndSetValue() instead of "setValue". JXPathContext will invoke your AbstractFactory when it discovers that an intermediate node of the path is null. It will not override existing nodes.*

```
public class AddressFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    public boolean createObject(JXPathContext context,
               Pointer pointer, Object parent, String name, int index){
     if ((parent instanceof Employee) && name.equals("address"){
       ((Employee)parent).setAddress(new Address());
       return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
 }

 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 context.setFactory(new AddressFactory());
 context.createPathAndSetValue("address/zipCode", "90190");
```